# How to fix Amazon.Rekognition.AmazonRekognitionException?

Tags: c#

I am getting AmazonRekognitionException as below when trying to run CompareFacesResponse, I am stuck, what should I do or check?

> Amazon.Rekognition.AmazonRekognitionException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown

AWS credentials access key and secret are checked and correct

```
    public static async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> Rekognition_Compare_Faces(string _source, string _target, string _bucketName)
    {
        const string HOSTNAME = "https://rekognition.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/";
        const string ACCESS_KEY = "my_access_key";
        const string ACCESS_SECRET = "my_secret_key";

        float _similarityThreshold = 70F;
        bool _ret = false;
        string _confidence = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            AmazonRekognitionConfig _config = new AmazonRekognitionConfig();
            _config.ServiceURL = HOSTNAME + _bucketName;

            AmazonRekognitionClient _rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET, _config);

            Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image _imageSource = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image();
            Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image _imageTarget = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image();

            Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object _s3_source = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object { Bucket = _bucketName, Name = _source };
            Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object _s3_target = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object { Bucket = _bucketName, Name = _target };

            CompareFacesRequest _compareFacesRequest = new CompareFacesRequest()
            {
                SourceImage = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image
                {
                    S3Object = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object
                    {
                        Bucket = HOSTNAME + _bucketName,
                        Name = _source
                    }
                },
                TargetImage = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image
                {
                    S3Object = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object
                    {
                        Bucket = HOSTNAME + _bucketName,
                        Name = _target
                    }
                },
                SimilarityThreshold = _similarityThreshold
            };

            // IT THROWN HERE!!   
            CompareFacesResponse _compareFacesResponse = await _rekognitionClient.CompareFacesAsync(_compareFacesRequest);

            // Display results
            foreach (CompareFacesMatch match in _compareFacesResponse.FaceMatches)
            {
                ComparedFace face = match.Face;
                BoundingBox position = face.BoundingBox;

                _confidence = match.Similarity.ToString(AppSettings.Decimal_Number_Format) + "%";
                _ret = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { await ClsMain.SaveLog("AWS.Compare_Faces: " + ex.ToString()); }
        finally { }

        return await Task.FromResult(new Tuple<bool, string>(_ret, _confidence));
    }
```

has anybody experience on this?

thanks a lot in advance

Regards
Don

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I tried adding `RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1` to my `AmazonRekognitionConfig` so it now looks like this:

```
            var config = new AmazonRekognitionConfig
            {
                ServiceURL = $"https://rekognition.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/{_awsSettings.BucketName}",
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
            };

            var client = new AmazonRekognitionClient(_awsSettings.AccessKey, _awsSettings.Secret, config);
```

This fixed the problem for me.